# how to get data type object from string

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, types

Let's say I have a list of dictionaries but in string format,

```
var = " [ {'key1': 'value1'}, {'key2': 'value2'} ] "
```

In the variable var, there is a list that contains two dictionaries and this whole thing is a string,
So my question is that how you can convert the type of var which is a string right now to a list.

Comment: Use [`eval`](https://realpython.com/python-eval-function/)

Comment: `import json; json.loads(var.replace("'", '"'))`

Answer (score 0):

Use `strip()` with `literal_eval` from `ast`:

```
import ast

var = " [ {'key1': 'value1'}, {'key2': 'value2'} ] "
var = var.strip()
print(ast.literal_eval(var))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `json` module to do this:

```
import json

var = " [ {'key1': 'value1'}, {'key2': 'value2'} ] "

obj = json.loads(var.replace("'", '"'))

print(obj)
```

Output:

```
[{'key1': 'value1'}, {'key2': 'value2'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ast evel

```
import ast
var = "[{'key1': 'value1'}, {'key2': 'value2'}]"
data = ast.literal_eval(var.strip())
print(type(data))
```

output

```
<class 'list'>
```